# fichero no encontrado, ruta equivocada en C#

Tags: c#

Estoy intentando cargar un fichero, al cual le indico la ruta del escritorio pero no se porque siempre me devuelve:

```
File not found!
```

El código es el siguiente:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleLauncher
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string filePath;
            filePath = "C:\\Users\\Androide\\Desktop\\prueba.exe";
            if (args.Length > 0)
            {
                //string filePath = args[0];
                if (File.Exists(filePath))
                {
                    // read the bytes from the application exe file
                    FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);
                    BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
                    byte[] bin = br.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
                    fs.Close();
                    br.Close();

                    // load the bytes into Assembly
                    Assembly a = Assembly.Load(bin);
                    // search for the Entry Point
                    MethodInfo method = a.EntryPoint;
                    if (method != null)
                    {
                        // create an istance of the Startup form Main method
                        object o = a.CreateInstance(method.Name);
                        // invoke the application starting point
                        method.Invoke(o, null);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write("File not found!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Basicamente le asigno la ruta de la siguiente manera:

```
string filePath;
filePath = "C:\\Users\\Androide\\Desktop\\prueba.exe";
```

El fichero se encuentra en el escritorio:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El error:

[image: error fichero no encontrado]

En este ejemplo al indicar `args.Length > 0` tenía que incluir algun argumento. Puedes ser resuelto poniendo `args.Length = 0`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Básicamente es por que en la ruta pones al usuario `Androide` y en tu imagen del explorador dice `Android`, debería quedar así:

```
filePath = "C:\\Users\\Android\\Desktop\\prueba.exe";
```

## Actualización

Debido a tu comentario mi explicación sería la siguiente: te envía ese mensaje no porque el archivo no exista, sino más bien porque validas que al llamar `console.exe` lleve argumentos al invocarlo, y como no le pones ninguno, por eso se va a la sentencia `else`:

Al poner en la consola de comandos `console.exe` no le pones ningún argumento, y el código funciona así:

```
if (args.Length > 0)
{
    //tu código
}
else
{
    Console.Write("File not found!");
}
```

No comprendo exactamente para que validas la existencia de argumentos, pero intenta llamar a `console.exe` de la siguiente forma:

```
console.exe 1
```

En este caso, ya llevará algún argumento y entrará directamente al `if` en lugar del `else`

Comment: no pone android porque mi usuario antes se llamaba android y le cambie el nombre a Androide.. corrijo la foto disculpa .. por ese fallo. me lo abrevia el windows.. subire una foto con la consola abierta

Comment: @OmarOmar listo, actualicé mi respuesta :)

Comment: si gracias estaba buscando alguna manera de hacerlo con argumentos y no lo indique gracias es importante